# SQL Invalid object name after exec statement

Tags: sql, exec

Here is the code

```
declare @test nvarchar(1000)

set @test = 'select * into #temp from mytable'

execute sp_executesql @test

select * from #temp
```

Then it returns: Invalid object name '#temp'.

I tried to create a temp table `temp` from `mytable`. However, it seems `#temp` is not created after `execute`. But if i take out `into #temp`, it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local temporary table (`#tmp`) is available in current session only that means `sp_executesql` execute in another session. for access to temp tables you should define global temporary table with two # (`##tmp`) and then your code will work in this way:

```
declare @test nvarchar(1000)

set @test = 'select * into ##temp from mytable'

execute sp_executesql @test

select * from ##temp
```